# Woocommerce: Trying to sort products on custom product page via SKU

Tags: cart, woocommerce

WooCommerce: Created a custom products page and used Woocommerce shortcode to show the products. I need to have the products in a specific order. Tried with ascending and descending on the SKU numbers. No luck.

eg.
[products skus="SKU4100,SKU4101,SKU4102,SKU4103" orderby="SKU" order="desc" ]

Although the numbers are on order on the page as well as in the databse, it does not show up in this order.

Any ideas, (There are 500+ items spread over 12 pages. This problem is only showing up on some pages.)
Guess the main question is, how do I specifically order the products?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my page and just corrected it.  I only had one product category that would not sort properly and the only difference between that and any other was that it began with the same letter as another product and category and it was the second in alphabetical order.  I changed the name of the product and of the category (I left the link alone) and it corrected itself.